# Can't install driver in Arch

Tags: linux, kernel, arch-linux, drivers, macintosh

I'm using Arch Linux, kernel 3.5.3 on a MacBook. I'm trying to get the keyboard backlight working. I found the driver in the AUR: http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=25467, but I'm having trouble compiling it.

When I run `makepkg` i get:

```
==> Making package: nvidia-bl 0.16.7-1 (Sat Sep  1 03:23:25 UTC 2012)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
Password: 
target not found: kernel26<2.6.34
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

I'm a new Linux user. Does this mean that I need to downgrade my Linux version to use this driver?

Comment: Keyboard backlight? What keyboard you got?

Comment: Just the stock keyboard that comes with the Macbook 5,1 Core 2 Duo aluminum. It has two buttons that control the brightness of the backlight. But I can't get it to work in Arch. I installed the nvidia-bl driver and modprobed it, added to rc.conf but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your PKGBUILD is outdated (0.16.7-1, but the current is 0.17.3-5). Try downloading the [nvidia-bl tarball](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nv/nvidia-bl/nvidia-bl.tar.gz) again and building it.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I installed it, then `modprobe nvidia-bl`, added to /etc/rc.conf, then restarted. But still not working. Any tips?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. (never used nvidia-bl)